# Create links to fancybox galleries using Jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I'm trying to have multiple fancybox-3 galleries on a page. However i do not want them to be visible until a link is clicked which calls the correct gallery. I've grouped the images to the relevant galleries. However clicking on the links results in the link being displayed as well. Can someone please show how i can call a fancybox-3 gallery using jQuery. Thank you.

```
<h2>fancyBox v3.2 - gallery links</h2>

<h4><a class="fancy-link" data-fancybox="bark">Bark gallery</a></h4>

<p class="imglist hidden">
  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/ndjyaOp0fOc/1500x1000" data-fancybox="bark">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ndjyaOp0fOc/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/A-fubu9QJxE/1500x1000" data-fancybox="bark">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/A-fubu9QJxE/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/rkkr6-2I4sg/1500x1000" data-fancybox="bark">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/rkkr6-2I4sg/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/mr_Tg4SI66A/1500x1000" data-fancybox="bark">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mr_Tg4SI66A/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/YEsedBccUEA/1500x1000" data-fancybox="bark">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/YEsedBccUEA/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Hw62tzAkXXE/1500x1000" data-fancybox="bark">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Hw62tzAkXXE/240x160" />
  </a>
</p>

<h4><a class="fancy-link" data-fancybox="landscape">Landscape gallery</a></h4>

<p class="imglist hidden">
  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Lzx4J_Pb3sk/1500x1000" data-fancybox="landscape">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Lzx4J_Pb3sk/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/cZVthlrnlnQ/1500x1000" data-fancybox="landscape">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/cZVthlrnlnQ/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/vddccTqwal8/1500x1000" data-fancybox="landscape">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/vddccTqwal8/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Sj5efgWguDs/1500x1000" data-fancybox="landscape">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Sj5efgWguDs/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Y7y7fe8hrh0/1500x1000" data-fancybox="landscape">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Y7y7fe8hrh0/240x160" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://source.unsplash.com/sYegwYtIqJg/1500x1000" data-fancybox="landscape">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/sYegwYtIqJg/240x160" />
  </a>
</p>
```

Codepen is here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvJrBg

Comment: Additionally i would like this to be possible a click listener/function just so my team doesn't have to edit the javascript to work. If i could just get it to work based of classes or data attributes that'd be great!

Comment: I guess you are looking for a feature that will be available starting from v3.3. See the last example of this demo - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/VyLOJX?editors=1000

Comment: @janis That's pretty much it! data-trigger is what i need. Anyway to do this in the interim?

Comment: Well, it was expected to be released this week, but I struggled with one issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally got something to work thanks to @janis help. Here's the code:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        // Options will go here
    });
    $('.fancy-link').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('a[data-fancybox="' + $(this).attr("data-trigger") + '"]').first().trigger('click');
    });
```

codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLoXZR